# Alignment using imakeidx in a gener

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

I'm trying to align an item of my index. Concretely, the item is created by using imakeidx. My most relevant code is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc,notindex]{tocbibind}% must go before imakeidx
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=\'Indice de t\'erminos,intoc]
\usepackage{ebgaramond} % Letra Garamond
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,snakes,shapes.geometric,fit,backgrounds,arrows.meta,decorations.markings,positioning,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}

\tikzset{module/.style={draw, minimum width=#1, minimum height=7mm, font=\sffamily}, module/.default=2cm, >=LaTeX}

\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}


\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.12
    ,colormap={mygreen}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,255)}
    }
    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\pagestyle{headings}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{alfabetico}{
  \fancyhead{}
%  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{Index}
}

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\thechapter. #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{{\thesection. #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.5\headheight}

\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Demostraci\'on}
\newcommand{\figura}[2]{\begin{figure}[h] \begin{center} \includegraphics[#2]{#1}  \end{center} \end{figure}

\vspace{-.8cm}}

\sloppy \frenchspacing
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-12pt/@{>}}

\newfont{\hueca}{msbm10}
\def \hu #1{\hbox{\hueca #1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\'Indice}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Cap\'itulo}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliograf\'ia}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{\'Indice de t\'erminos}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\'Indice de figuras}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\'Indice de tablas}

\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{corolario}[teorema]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lema}[teorema]{Lema}
\newtheorem{lem}[teorema]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[teorema]{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{ex}[teorema]{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{cor}[teorema]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{thm}[teorema]{Teorema}
\newtheorem{rem}[teorema]{Nota}

\newtheorem{construction}[teorema]{Construcci\'on}%

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{vacio}[theorem]{}

\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Nota}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Ejemplo}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{definition}[teorema]{Definici\'on}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{nota}[teorema]{Nota}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{notation}[teorema]{Notaci\'on}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{question}[teorema]{Pregunta}

\baselineskip=7,0mm

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{titlepage}

\fontsize{0.9cm}{1cm}\selectfont
\centerline{{\bf Topolog\'ia General}}
\vskip0.05cm \centerline{\bf para principiantes}

\vskip3.5cm

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\include{Libro_intro}

\pagestyle{headings} \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark} \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\newpage

\chapter{Teor\'ia de...}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%               ANEXO

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

{\small
\include{Libro_anexo}
\cleardoublepage}

\pagestyle{headings} \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark} \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%               BIBLIOGRAFIA

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
{\small
\include{Libro_bibliografia}
\cleardoublepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%               ÍNDICE DE TÉRMINOS

\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\'Indice de t\'erminos}
\printindex % Que ponga el índice aquí
%\printindex[people]  %Añade índice de palabras


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%               NOTACIÓN

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
{\small
\include{Libro_simbolos}
\cleardoublepage}

\end{document}
```

I obtain this:

[image]

As we can see, appears a duplicated item and the items Bibliografía and Notación are following a bad alignement. Please, tell me how I can fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please extend your example to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be used to reproduce the image you are showing (maybe you also should adapt the image). Currently the code results in no output and does not contain a table of contents nor a bibliography (also shown in the image) or similar. So it is hard so say, why the alignment of the entries are different.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of loading `anysize` in addition to `geometry` and so overwriting the settings of `geometry`, I would recommend to just use `geometry` so setup the margins you want.

Comment: BTW: `imakeidx` provides option `intoc` for `\makeindex`. Maybe you should read section 3 of the manual.

Comment: cabohah: I have readen it. So I write \makeindex[title=\'Indice de t\'erminos, intoc=true]?

Comment: cabohah: that solution has created a duplicate of the same item (placed under the previous one), and again not well align    :(

Answer (score 1):

1. It makes no sense to use `anysize` (which is obsolete) together with `geometry`.
2. You don't say how you get the bibliography in the TOC.
3. You don't say how you get the index in the TOC.

Working setup (remove `showframe` that's used here to show the margins of the text block):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc,notindex]{tocbibind}% must go before imakeidx
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=\'Indice de t\'erminos,intoc]

\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm,showframe}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Something}

Text \index{sample}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{A} Something

\end{thebibliography}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use a file Bibliography.tex and then I include it:

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
{\small
\include{Bibliography}
\cleardoublepage}

The same with Anexo.tex and Notation.tex. Now with your solution I have duplicated Bibliography (one bad alignement), Anexo appears in the middle of the index and Notation appears before to Indice de terminos  :(

Comment: @LH8 Remove all the manual `\addcontentsline` commands.

Comment: It is removed. I add new image and indication in the initial post. Thank you very much for the support!